# Transformer duality model with capacitor

Tags: capacitor, transformer

I want to know if it is possible to transfer power through the instruments using capacitors? As you know instruments such as Marx generator actually increase the power but we aim to have sth to work as transformer (equal power transmission)

Comment: There is no duality.

Answer (score 0):

It sure is possible to transfer power with capacitors (however there is no duality with transformers) here is a circuit that demonstrates power transfer with capacitors to provide isolation. The caps block DC (and provide isolation), the IC generates a square wave for the power transfer.

[image]
Source: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/4553